# Scrollbars showing up over header and footer on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, layout

I'm developing a mobile application to look like it's running on an iPad. When the page initially loads, if the body of the page is beyond the window/screen size, the scrollbars for the page show up "over" the header and footer. But after you refresh the page, then the scrollbars show up BETWEEN the header and the footer (aka it's only over the body), which is what I want.

I'm not able to duplicate the exact behavior (where the scrollbars only show up over the body after a refresh) on jsfiddle, but it at least shows you the scrollbar over the entire page.

Any help is appreciated...

[Here's the jsfiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/andegre/6phXv/)

Here's the code that I have:
CSS:

```
.locationListItem {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.locationListPrimary {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: medium;
}

.locationListSecondary {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: smaller;
}
```

HTML:

```
@section header {
    @*
        Recommeneded to use an h1 element, but can contain any kind of element, but make sure to add the TrailsHeaderPrimary class to get the proper styling... 
        Using an h1 element will get the proper padding around the header line. To see the difference, try doing an h1 vs p *@
    <h1 class="testHeaderPrimary">Search Locations</h1>
}

<div style="top: 15px; left: 15px; width: 100%; z-index: 2">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search/Filter Locations...">
        @foreach (var location in Model.AvailableLocations)
        {
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="ui-grid-b">
                        <div class="ui-block-a"><span class="locationListPrimary" style="width: 20%">@location.Thing</span></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b"><span class="locationListPrimary" style="width: 20%">@location.Person</span></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-c"><span class="locationListSecondary" style="width: 60%">@location.Year | @location.Stuff | @location.Type</span></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>

@section navBar1 {
    <a href="/Search/Index" style="font-size: x-large">Search</a>
}

@section navBar2 {
    <a href="/Location/Index" style="font-size: x-large">Location</a>
}

@section navBar3 {
    <a href="/LocationStrip/Index" style="font-size: x-large">LocationStrip</a>
}

@section navBar4 {
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" style="font-size: x-large; height: 60px" target="_blank">StackOverflow</a>
}

@section navBar5 {
    <a href="#" style="font-size: x-large" target="_blank">NA</a>
}
```

Javascript (from the Layout):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    resetScreenSize();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    resetScreenSize();
});

var resetScreenSize = function () {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var header = $('#testHeader');
    var headerHeight = header.outerHeight();
    var footer = $("#testFooter");
    var footerHeight = footer.outerHeight() - 1;

    $(".ui-grid-a").height(windowHeight - footerHeight - headerHeight);
    $("#panelMain").height(windowHeight - footerHeight - headerHeight);
};
```

**Update 1:**
Here's the body from the layout file...

```
<body style="height: 100%">
    <div id="main" role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content" style="padding: 0; height: 100%;">
        <div id="testHeader" data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
            @RenderSection("header", false)
        </div>

        <div class="ui-grid-a" data-theme="a">
            <div id="panelMain" style="overflow: auto;">
                <div class="ui-content">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="testFooter" data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" style="height: 60px; display: block;">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li>@RenderSection("navBar1", true)</li> <!-- Home/1 should be reserved for the home screen -->
                    <li>@RenderSection("navBar2", true)</li>
                    <li>@RenderSection("navBar3", true)</li>
                    <li>@RenderSection("navBar4", true)</li>
                    <li>@RenderSection("navBar5", true)</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

**Update 2:**
One of the tabs at the bottom goes to a page where it's split 20%/80%. That page uses a different layout to do the 20/80. When that page first loads, it does NOT incorporate my style in the "head" tag that looks like this:

```
#panelLeft {
    width: 20%;
    border-right: 3px solid
}

#panelMain {
    width: 80%;
}
```

But as soon as I refresh the page, all of the styling is applied. I'm beginning to wonder if it's not applying my custom styling that I specify in each of the "head" tags in my layout pages. Should I be placing those in a separate css file instead?

Comment: This question is no longer needed because project is getting converted to angular SPA. I did not have a chance to try and of the suggested answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only idea I have that I can give is. Make the body's height fixed and have a property of `overflow-y:auto;`.

Also, ideally, you want to make the header, body and footer's total height the same with the height of the view height, browser's height.

So fix `height = ((header's height + footer's height) - browser's current height)`. That's my formula.

To do that, either javascript/jQuery or css.

**EDIT**

Here's a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/4RLZv/

Forgot my JS/JQ

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var height = $('#head').outerHeight() + $('#foot').outerHeight();
        height = $(window).innerHeight() - height;
    $('#body').css('height',height);
});
```

Comment: I may have already done that...I've added the body from the layout file.

Comment: Not exactly on the body element, but it's on the div that's wrapping the @RenderBody() section. Which, I think, is why it works after a page refresh.

Comment: @ganders I'm guessing, the problem is with your javascript/jquery. The time it takes to load, calculate and apply your 'settings'. I'm not sure now as I have had tons of other similar problems before with different causes and solutions. Btw, check out mine if it helps even a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
.ui-grid-a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 68px;
    bottom: 63px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Also you can play with property width + property margin:auto

```
.ui-grid-a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 68px;
    bottom: 63px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin: auto;
    width: 900px;
}
```

Where width you should set for each size of display separately, e.g.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .ui-grid-a {
        width: 600px;
     }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 968px) {
    .ui-grid-a {
        width: 800px;
     }
}
```

Just play with it!